# Practical Role Based Data Access Controls in ASP.NET MVC / SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, security, database-design, data-structures

I have an ASP.NET MVC + SQL Server application with 250 simultaneous users daily which uses AD/NTLM SSO to do all the authorization using a custom authorization security class that control access to controllers & Actions based on users & groups.

A dilemma recently came up where the 50K+ account records of the database are going to be managed by different groups to varying degree's:

- All users will be able to view most records certain records can only
- be edited by certain users/groups of specific departments There will
- be an admin & support groups that will be able to edit any group owned records
- etc.

This is not a problem of who has access to what features/forms/etc. in the controllers, but instead a dilemma of data ownership restrictions that must be imposed. I am guessing this means I need some additional layer of security for row level security.

I am looking for a pragmatic & robust way to tackle data ownership within the current application framework with minimal performance hits since it is likely the same thing will need to be imposed on other much larger tables of data. Initially there will be about 5 ownership groups, but creeping up to 25 to 100 in the near future.

Sadly there are no cut and dry business rules that are hard and fast that can be implemented here.. there is no rhyme or reason make sense of who owns what except the record primary key id.

To try to fix it I was thinking of creating a table of `owner_roles` and map it to the `users` table then create another table called `accounts_ownership` that looks something like:

```
tbl(PK),row(PK),owner(PK),view,create,modify,delete
accounts,1,hr,1,1,1,1
accounts,1,it,1,0,0,0
accounts,2,hr,1,1,1,1
accounts,2,it,1,1,1,1
accounts,3,it,1,0,0,0
```

But in doing so that would create a table that was 250K lines and could easily get some crappy performance. Looking at sites like Facebook and others this must be a common thing that has to be implemented, but I am hesitant to introduce a table like that since it could create serious performance issues.

The other way I thought this may be implemented is by adding an extra column to the accounts table that is a compound field that is comma separated that would contain the owner(s) with a coded set of rights ie.:

```
id   owners
1    ,hr,    
2    ,hr,
3    ,hr,it,
4    ,it,
```

And then add a custom class to search using the 'like' statement.. provided the logged in users role was "it" and the comma's were reserved and not allowed in owners names:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE owners LIKE '%,it,%'
```

... however this really just feels wrong from a DBA perspective (ugly as hell) and a maintenance nightmare.

Any practical approaches on how I could implement this without destroying my site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primarily for performance reasons, I went with the less elegant approach listed. It took some doing, but there are careful application controls that had to be created to enforce things like no comma's in the id's.

Comment: I just wanted to note since I was asked by someone else why i had a comma on the owners column before AND after each group; i.e.: ,hr,group1,it,

Answer (score 0):

Start with [Role-based access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control), you can possibly skip the roles from the pure definition but should be able to implement it like this:

- Every user can be in one or more groups like admin, support, it, hr
- Every data row has an owner like it, hr

On Access, check the access: an admin can see and edit all rows. Support+it sees every row and can edit those from it etc. This way you need only (user-groups + row-access) new rows in your database, not (user-groups * row-access).

User groups in your scenario should be possible to hardcode in your application, in a CMS there is generally a table defining what rights to assign to each user group - complicating the coding but very flexible.

Roles in the original concept allow a user to select what rights he/she wants to use, there would be a "Unlock with admin rights" or the like in your interface.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but that doesn't really offer any practical advice. Like I said in the original post there is no rhyme or reason for which records are owned by which group, which invalidates your suggestion.